# Regex fails in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a following regex expression in javascript

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[(]?[2-9]\d{2}[)]?[\-. :]?[2-9]\d{2}[\-. :]?\d{4}$");
return this.optional(element) || (reg.test(value));
```

in my code reg.test(value) return false even on correct values: for instance 222 222 2222 or 222-222-2222. All regex testers(especially [this](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/) one, which calls the same methods) show that regex matches the expression. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var reg = /^[(]?[2-9]\d{2}[)]?[\-. :]?[2-9]\d{2}[\-. :]?\d{4}$/;
return this.optional(element) || (reg.test(value));
```

Or also:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[(]?[2-9]\\d{2}[)]?[\\-. :]?[2-9]\\d{2}[\\-. :]?\\d{4}$");
return this.optional(element) || (reg.test(value));
```

Comment: Searched for this a very long time! Didn't know we had to double escape the special chars like `\s` --> `\\s` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried a lot, not realized \ shall be replaced to \\

Comment: How do you correctly escape a double quotation mark? (") Since \" within a string literal escapes it, but with regards to pattern matching, \\" causes your script to become invalid?

Comment: In this case you should add `\\\"`

Answer (score 4):

The `\`s are being swallowed by the string literal.

You should use a regex literal instead:

```
var reg = /^[(]?[2-9]\d{2}[)]?[\-. :]?[2-9]\d{2}[\-. :]?\d{4}$/;
```

Answer (score 2):

I see one potential cause of troubles: if you're creating a new Regular Expression using the `RegExp` function, you'll have to escape backslashes twice - once for the JavaScript engine, and once for the RegEx engine.

You can test if this is causing the troubles by doing

```
var reg = /^[(]?[2-9]\d{2}[)]?[\-. :]?[2-9]\d{2}[\-. :]?\d{4}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the regex in as a string so all of the occurrences of `\d` should be `\\d` because when the regex string is sent to the interpreter the `\d` character is not interpreted as a `\` and a `d` but just a `d` adding the extra slash escapes the other slash so the `\\d` is interpreted as a `\` and a `d`.  Also I suggest one other change, the `[(]` should be replaced with `\\(` because the character class only contains one character and therefore has no point.